# Predictive Intelligence mail display link

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

When I try implementing [Creating Predictive Email Content](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/predictive_intelligence/predictive_email/creating_predictive_email_content/), the generated recommendation (an image with a link) will use the catalog `ProductLink` field as the link URL.
Is it possible to override such behavior?

Also: for prices the standard currency used is dollar, would it be possible to change it as desired?

Answer (score 2):

So PI uses a version of Ampscript which is documented here:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_pb_ampscript_functions_for_email_recommendations.htm&type=5

These are the only ampscript which is supported within Email displays in Email Recommendations

You have two options to solve your use case. In your catalog populate a filed with the price and currency, so your catalog would have a custom field called EuroRegPrice/EuroSale Price and then You would supply the value '€ 50,00'

Then in the email display you would use `%%EuroRegPrice%%` as opposed to `%%RegularPrice%%`

The 2nd options is to use the ampscript from the doc above

and your display code would look something like

`€ %%RegularPriceMain%%,%%RegularPriceFractional%%`

regarding the link being used you can replace `%%imagelink%%` which any field from the catalog, but unsure what the use case would be here

An example using the default code would be

```
<div style="font-size:12px;color:black;width:150px; text-align:center;">
<img style="max-width:150px;" src="%%ImageLink%%">
<p>%%ProductName%%</p>
%%[ if SalePrice &lt; RegularPrice then ]%%
<s>Regular Price: € %%RegularPriceMain%%.%%RegularPriceFractional%%</s><br>
<span style="color:red;">Sale Price: € %%SalePriceMain%%,%%SalePriceFractional%%</span>
%%[ else ]%%
€ %%RegularPriceMain%%.%%RegularPriceFractional%%
%%[ endif ]%%
<p>%%Description%%</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a personalization string, then, yes, you should be able to override it.

You have a wide range of [AMPScript functions](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/#alphalist) at your disposal.

Here's a quick example:

```
%%[

var @productName, @regularPrice, @salePrice, @productLink

set @productName = AttributeValue("ProductName")
set @regularPrice = AttributeValue("regularPrice")
set @salePrice = AttributeValue("salePrice")
set @productLink = AttributeValue("productLink")

set @productName = replace(@productName,"XL","Extra Large")
set @regularPrice = formatCurrency(@regularPrice,"de-DE")
set @salePrice = formatCurrency(@salePrice,"de-DE")
set @productLink = concat(@productLink,"&whee=1")

]%%
<div>
<p>Product: <a href="%%=redirectto(@productLink)=%%">%%=v(@productName)=%%</a><p>
<p>Regular Price: %%=v(@RegularPrice)=%%</p>
<p>Sale Price: %%=v(@salePrice)=%%</p>    
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Adam, I think that would work for normal email within marketing cloud mail module, I am referring to the predictive intelligence mail recommendation. In this case the system generates a statica image, meaning that the command <p>Product: <a href="%%=redirectto(@productLink)=%%">%%=v(@productName)=%%</a><p> would not be useful

Comment: Then use the same philosophy with the `%%imageLink%%` personalization string (instead of `ProductName`) as referenced on [Styling Predictive Email Displays](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/predictive_intelligence/predictive_email/creating_predictive_email_content/styling_predictive_email_displays/)

Comment: Hi Adam, I tried the following:

`%%[var @ProductLink
    set @ProductLink = "http://www.google.com"
    ]%%

    <div>
    <img src="%%ImageLink%%" />
    <p>Product: <a href="%%ProductLink%%">%%ProductName%%</a><p>
    <p>Regular Price: %%RegularPrice%%</p>
    <p>Sale Price: %%SalePrice%%</p>    
    </div>
]%%`

The generated link still points to the catalog product url though:
https://7285441.recs.igodigital.com/rr/v2/57a860780200b56fc3000000/l/1/testPI@google.com

Image url
https://pi-templates.s3.amazonaws.com/production/57a86066beba1302ad000000/XCode1~1.png
Thank you

Comment: You aren't referencing the variable you set...see my example in the div for `@productLink`

Comment: I am sorry but I really don't get it...  referring to your example: 
'<div>
<p>Product: <a href="%%=redirectto(@productLink)=%%">%%=v(@productName)=%%</a><p>
<p>Regular Price: %%=v(@RegularPrice)=%%</p>
<p>Sale Price: %%=v(@salePrice)=%%</p>    
</div>'
 this code will be rendered as an image (see here https://pi-templates.s3.amazonaws.com/production/57a86066beba1302ad000000/XCode1~1.png) so the link you are setting is not really clickable. Am I missing something? I thought the AMPscript could be used to override the catalog field that the PI system would use

Comment: Set the link in your div to `<a href="%%=redirectto(@productLink)=%%">%%=v(@productName)=%%</a>`

Comment: Hi Adam, I did exactly as suggested. Display code:
`%%[
var @ProductLink
set @ProductLink = "http://www.google.com"
]%%
<div>
<img src="%%ImageLink%%" />
<p>Product: <a href="%%=redirectto(@ProductLink)=%%">%%=v(@ProductName)=%%</a><p>
<p>Regular price: %%RegularPrice%%</p>
<p>Sale price: %%SalePrice%%</p>    
</div>`

Comment: But as you can see from the result here it is not working:
`<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="https://7285441.recs.igodigital.com/rr/v2/57a860780200b56fc3000000/l/1/testPI@google.com">
        <img src="https://7285441.recs.igodigital.com/rr/v2/57a860780200b56fc3000000/i/1/testPI@google.com"/>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>`